# How to convert if else shorthand to normal if else case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

Below code, I update the react hook with if-else shorthand condition. To understand exactly this, I try to write it in normal if-else condition, but I couldn't. What is the equal case of this shorthand conditions?

This is working code.

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

function addProduct(product){
  const ProductExist = array.find((item) => item.id === product.id);
  setArray(
   array.map((item) =>
   item.id === product.id
   ? { ...ProductExist, quantity: ProductExist.quantity + 1 }
   : item
   )
 );
}
```

This is my try according to the solutions of other topics. But it gives error.

```
setTestArray(array.map((item) => {
  return if(item.id === product.id){
   return { ...ProductExist, quantity: ProductExist.quantity + 1 }
  }else{
   return item
  }
}
```

Comment: `return if` makes little sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra return

It should be like this:

```
setTestArray(array.map((item) => {
  if(item.id === product.id){
   return { ...ProductExist, quantity: ProductExist.quantity + 1 }
  }else{
   return item
  }
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  setArray(
   array.map((item) =>
     if(item.id === product.id){
       return { ...ProductExist, quantity: ProductExist.quantity + 1 };
     } else {
       return item;
     }
   )
```